# Scrolling a child window "overflows" to the parent window

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a parent window and a child window, something like:

```
class CChildDlg : public CDialog
{
    ...
}

class CParentDlg : public CDialog
{
    CChildDlg m_cChildDlg;
    ...
}
```

In the parent's `OnInitDialog` function, I create the child window:

```
m_cChildDlg.CreateEx(0,
                     WC_STATIC,
                     NULL,
                     WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|SS_NOTIFY,
                     {0,0,width,height},
                     this,
                     0);
```

I can scroll the child window easily using `m_cChildDlg.ScrollWindow(xAmount, yAmount)`.

The problem is that I have a few other controls in the parent window right above the child window (tool-bar, etc), which the child window "overrides" when scrolled upwards.

I tried calling `SetWindowPos` in order to set the child window behind the other controls, but that did not seem to make any difference.

This is what the MSDN says about these two functions:

- [`ScrollWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa250314.aspx)
- [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx)

But I haven't been able to find anything related to this problem, so I'm guessing there might be something else that I'm missing here.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code calling `ScrollWindow()`, I guess you're not or incorrectly using the parameter `lpClipRect`.

Comment: @zett42: Done. I only pass `xAmount` and `yAmount`, while leaving the other two arguments in their default values (both of which are `NULL`). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a clip rectangle (parameter `lpClipRect`) to `ScrollWindow()`. From the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa250314.aspx):

> If lpClipRect is NULL, no clipping is performed on the scroll
>   rectangle.

That's why you get the overflow.

You can fix it like this:

```
CRect rc; 
m_cChildDlg.GetClientRect(rc);
m_cChildDlg.ScrollWindow(xAmount, yAmount, nullptr, rc);
```

Comment: Great, this solves my problem in a partial manner. The child window indeed doesn't "override" any of the parent window contents. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck with a problem of the child window contents all smeared. Like, the part that was just scrolled out remains painted. Would you be able to guess what the reason for this might be? Thank you!!!

Comment: @goodvibration From the reference: _The application will eventually receive a WM_PAINT message notifying it that the region needs repainting. To repaint the uncovered area at the same time the scrolling is done, call the UpdateWindow member function immediately after calling ScrollWindow._

Comment: Yes, I've read that and tried that before asking. No luck here.

Comment: @goodvibration Do you have custom WM_PAINT or WM_ERASEBKNGD handler for the child window?

Comment: No, neither. I tried adding an `OnPaint` handler, from which I tried two different things: 1. Calling `CDialog::OnPaint()`. 2. Calling `GetParent()->OnPaint()`. None of those resolved the problem.

Comment: @goodvibration With the original issue resolved I suggest creating a new question for the remaining issue.